# Looping attributes brand

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im trying to loop all my attributes brands, but is blank, and doesnt give any error, cant figure out what is wrong with my code.

Im quite sure the problem is in my code, since i already put static data in my view, and is working fine, i also notice the problem was in the "$val[0]=", for some reason i cant get the first charecters of the string "$val".

Here is my source:

```
<div class="brandlist">
    <div class="lettermenu">
        <ul>
            <li style="float:left;">A-Z Brands List</li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#A">A</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#B">B</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#C">C</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#D">D</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#E">E</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#F">F</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#G">G</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#H">H</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#I">I</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#J">J</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#K">K</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#L">L</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#M">M</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#N">N</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#O">O</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#P">P</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#Q">Q</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#R">R</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#S">S</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#T">T</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#U">U</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#V">V</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#W">W</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#X">X</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#Y">Y</a></li>
            <li><a class="letterlink" href="#Z">Z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <?php

    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
    $alpha="A";

    foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
            $attributeArray[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
    }foreach($attributeArray as $key=>$val){
    $url = "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/"."?manufacturer%5B%5D=".$key;

    if ($val[0]==="") {}
    elseif ($alpha===$val[0]){ ?>
        <div class="brandname"><a href="<?php echo $url?>"> <?php echo $val; ?></a></div><?php
    }
    else {
        echo "<div id='". $val[0] ."' class='letter'>".$val[0]."</div>";
    ?>
    <div class="brandname"><a href="<?php echo $url?>"> <?php echo $val; ?></a></div>

        <?php
    $alpha=$val[0];
    }}
    ?>


    ?>
</div>
<style>
    .brandlist {margin:auto;}
    .brandname {min-width:200px;float:left;width:25%;padding:10px;}
    .letter {display:inline-block;width:100%;background:#9F9F9F;padding:10px;}
    .lettermenu {margin-top:0px;text-align: center;}
    .letterlink {min-width:20px;width:3.4%;float:left;margin-right:0px;}
</style>
```

Comment: I would suggest to start by changing your comparison operator from `===` to `==` .   $a === $b is TRUE if $a is `equal` to $b, and they are `of the same type`. $a ==  $b is TRUE if $a is `equal` to $b after type was changed. More on the subject: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#type.comparisons-strict

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for getting the collecion on you attribute:

```
<?php
$name='manufacturer';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
print_r($attributeOptions);
?>
```